# Do Distinguished Names always contain Domain info?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

Do Distinguished Names in Active Directory always contain domain info?

```
CN=User Name,OU=UserAccounts,DC=some,DC=company,DC=com
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is YES

According to technet: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc977992.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> ### Distinguished Name
>
> Objects are located within Active Directory domains
>   according to a hierarchical path, ***which includes the labels of the
>   Active Directory domain name*** and each level of container objects. The
>   full path to the object is defined by the distinguished name (also
>   known as a "DN"). The name of the object itself, separate from the
>   path to the object, is defined by the relative distinguished name.